# try not to do sth vs. try to avoid doing sth

Tags: sentence-meaning

*Try not to offend him from now on.*

*Try to avoid offending him from now on*

Is there any shade of difference in the meanings of above 2 sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, I think, a very slight difference. "Try to avoid offending him" suggests that you will need to make a deliberate effort not to offend him; it implies that you are likely to offend him unless you are careful. "Try not to offend him" does not have this connotation.